# How should I check the result of a fetch of DB?

Tags: laravel

I would like to check if $test gets the value correcly.

```
$test = \DB::connection('stacks')->table('phones')->where('user_id', $id)->first();
Log::debug($test);
Log::debug("".json_decode($test));
```

An error happned.

Argument 1 passed to Facade\Ignition\LogRecorder\LogMessage::__construct() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in

Comment: you can die dump the value as such dd($test)

Comment: `$test` will be an object. You can't use an object as the log message. Maybe you can use it in the context (i.e. the array that you could pass as a 2nd parameter to `Log::debug('message', [ 'context' ])`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do dd($test). Also it is really useful if you use laravel's debug bar.
In order to install do this:

> composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar